# Owl Carousel: Cannot read property 'visibleItems' of undefined

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I'm not sure if this is a problem, but I get this error in my Console, and it drives me crazy 'cause I prefer to have to errors on my pages.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibleItems' of undefined**.
It points to this line of code:
`var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;`

I created a JSFiddle to replicate this: http://jsfiddle.net/j2esf0bn/3/

```
<div id="main_image">
    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div>
</div>
<div id="product_thumbnails">
    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var sync1 = jQuery("#sync1");
    var sync2 = jQuery("#sync2");

    sync1.owlCarousel({
        jsonPath: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71195383/customData.json',
        jsonSuccess: customDataSuccess1,
        singleItem: true,
        slideSpeed: 1000,
        pagination: true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x'></i>"],
        afterAction: syncPosition,
        responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
        rewindNav: false,
        lazyLoad: true
    });

    sync2.owlCarousel({
        jsonPath: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71195383/customData.json',
        jsonSuccess: customDataSuccess2,
        items: 5,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 5],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 5],
        itemsTablet: [768, 5],
        itemsMobile: [479, 4],
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x'></i>"],
        pagination: false,
        rewindNav: false,
        slideSpeed: 1000,
        responsiveRefreshRate: 100,
        afterInit: function (el) {
            el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
        }

    });

    function syncPosition(el) {
        var current = this.currentItem;
        jQuery("#sync2")
            .find(".owl-item")
            .removeClass("synced")
            .eq(current)
            .addClass("synced");
        if (jQuery("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined) {
            center(current);
        }

    }

    jQuery("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = jQuery(this).data("owlItem");
        sync1.trigger("owl.goTo", number);
    });

    function center(number) {
        var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;

        var num = number;
        var found = false;
        for (var i in sync2visible) {
            if (num === sync2visible[i]) {
                var found = true;
            }
        }

        if (found === false) {
            if (num > sync2visible[sync2visible.length - 1]) {
                sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length + 2);
            } else {
                if (num - 1 === -1) {
                    num = 0;
                }
                sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
            }
        } else if (num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length - 1]) {
            sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1]);
        } else if (num === sync2visible[0]) {
            sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - 1);
        }
    }


    function customDataSuccess1(data) {
        var content = "";
        for (var i in data["items"]) {

            var img = data["items"][i].img;
            var alt = data["items"][i].alt;

            content += "<img class=\"lazyOwl\"  data-src=\"http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/" + img + "\" alt=\"" + alt + "\">";
        }
        jQuery("#sync1").html(content);
    }

    function customDataSuccess2(data) {
        var content = "";

        for (var i in data["items"]) {

            var img = data["items"][i].img;
            var alt = data["items"][i].alt;

            if (data["thumbnails"] === true) {
                img = img.replace(".jpg", '-th.jpg');
            }

            content += "<img src=\"http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/" + img + "\" alt=\"" + alt + "\">";
        }
        jQuery("#sync2").html(content);
    }


});
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to interpret or fix this error.  I've searched the net, but couldn't find anything that answers my question.

Any help appreciated!

***EDIT***

All attempts at trying to resolve this error has lead to other errors.

The error only appears in the console once when the page is loaded.  After the page load, the carousel operates as expected.

So, in conclusion, I will not let this error upset me further, and simply try to ignore it when viewing the console log on this specific page.  **However**, if anyone has found a way to fix this error, please do not hesitate to post your answer.

It appears that the error is related to using ***JSON along with synced carousels***.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the elements aren't rendering in time before you call data attribute on your owl carousel.  I have also changed the way the visible items are gathered.

```
var sync2visible = sync2.data().owlCarousel.owl.visibleItems;
```

Take a look at this fiddle, does it work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/j2esf0bn/5/

Comment: I had a look at the fiddle, but still see that error in the console. :/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the carousel doesn't need this information immediately. I fixed the console error with a simple if statement and changed the line from

```
var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
```

to

```
var sync2visible = false;
if (typeof sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl != 'undefined')
   sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
```